# How to validate model data with JPA?

Tags: java, validation, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to get JPA validation to work, however it seems that the validation annotations are ignored. I found this example of JPA validation on SO: [JPA Entity Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323111/jpa-entity-validation), but it does not work for me. The `@NotNull` and `@Size` annotations seem to be ignored.

As in the answer mentioned above I use only two classes:

Customer.java:

```
package com.validation.test;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "customerIdSeq", sequenceName = "T_CUSTOMER_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "customerIdSeq")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 80)
    private String name;

    public Customer() {};

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
}
```

CustomerTest.java:

```
package com.validation.test.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.junit.*;

import com.validation.test.Customer;

public class CustomerTest {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createEntityManagerFactory() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        emf.close();
    }

    @Before
    public void beginTransaction() {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    @After
    public void rollbackTransaction() {
        if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void nameTooShort() {
        try {
            Customer customer = new Customer("bo");
            em.persist(customer);
            em.flush();
            fail("Expected ConstraintViolationException wasn't thrown.");
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            assertEquals(1, e.getConstraintViolations().size());
            ConstraintViolation<?> violation = e.getConstraintViolations().iterator().next();

            assertEquals("name", violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
            assertEquals(Size.class, violation.getConstraintDescriptor().getAnnotation().annotationType());
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.validation.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>    
    </repositories>    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc5</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>    
    <build>
        <finalName>wwd-bs</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.16</version>
                </plugin>    
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>    
    </build>
</project>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.validation.test.Customer</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The test fails at the `fail(...)` so the exception is never thrown.

How can I make (any) validation work with JPA? I cannot use Hibernate or Spring.

Thank you for your help

EDIT: added hibernate-validator to pom.xml (with no effect)

Comment: You have included only the validation API, but no implementation of that. Check the @wds' link and copy the part with <dependency> to your pom.xml

Comment: please see first comment on @wds' answer

Comment: I have seen that, but it does not seem, that you made what I said (your pom.xml shows that)...

Comment: I added the pom.xml change as an EDIT to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your pom.xmls.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

And set validation property to AUTO this must to be enable in persistence.xml

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="AUTO" />
```

Or do it progrmatically.

```
final Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> errors = validator.validate(object, classes);
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. I did not have to set the validation property to AUTO.

Comment: addendum: I also had to update the eclipselink version (now using 2.5.0) as suggested by @wds. With version 1.2.0 I got a ValidationException HV000041 whenever something was being validated.

Comment: Be careful when using the auto mode for [hibernate validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/additionalmodules.html#d0e3900) : "AUTO: *if* Bean Validation is present in the classpath". Better set it to CALLBACK to get an error when no validator is found on the classpath.

Comment: using maven for tests, CALLBACK allowed me to find every place where I forgot to add a test dependency on EL implementation, thank you @secure_paul

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a runtime implementation of the validator on your classpath? Typically people seem to use [hibernate validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/). (e.g. indeed by adding hibernate-validator to your pom.xml)

edit: Your version of EclipseLink also looks quite old, it should be a JPA2 implementation. If it is a JPA1 implementation, you should register your own event listener, which will be a bit more work. You can find some hints in the [eclipse docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-checkconstraints-orm-hibernateevent) (scroll down to JPA section), but it looks like you'll have to slightly edit the standard validators to make it work. [This blog](http://antoniogoncalves.org/2010/03/03/bean-validation-with-jpa-1-0/) might be helpful.

Comment: If by that you mean have a dependency on hibernate-validator in my pom.xml, I have tried that without any effect. If that was not what you meant, could you please be a little more specific? I am new to the whole JavaEE/JPA/maven environment.

Comment: @svenhuebner That was indeed what I meant. I've come up with a few other likely culprits above.